# Solve $\frac{A}{x^2}=\exp{(-\frac{x}{B})}$ for $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is it possible to solve $\frac{A}{x^2}=\exp{(-\frac{x}{B})}$ for $x$?

A and B are constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,
using the Lambert W-function.
Given $z$,
$W(z)$ solves
$z = W(z)^{W(z)}$.

Putting you equation
into this form 
is a matter of algebra.
Here is a start:
taking the square root
of each side,
$\sqrt{A}
=x e^{-x/2B}
$.